# Does English have a saying for "The person who orders something is the one has to pay for it"?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains, proverb-requests, german

In German, we have the saying *Wer bestellt, bezahlt*, which translates
literally into *Who(ever) orders, pays* in English. Is there a 
corresponding English idiomatic expression or proverbial refrain for this 
concept where the person who orders something is the one who has to pay for
it?

The context that made me wonder is the situation 
[here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/18122/17765). Person A is upset by person B who has wrongly parked their car in person 
A’s way (on private ground). An answer suggested that A could call a towing
service to remove B’s car. Because it was person A who ordered the towing 
service to remove the car, over here the towing service’s bill would go to
person A under the principle of *Wer bestellt, bezahlt*, so A pays it. It’s 
then up to person A, bill in hand, to go after person B for the money which
A has already paid.

The idea here is that placing responsibility for payment on whoever calls
the towing company will safeguard against unnecessary towing or expensive
practical jokes because in such frivolous cases, person A will not be able
to later recover the money they’ve already paid the towing company from
person B.

Another situation where I’d to apply this idiom is the following.  Consider
ordering some custom part, say at a 3D printing service. You receive the
print, but don’t like it after all. It’s not defective, damaged, or badly 
printed; you simply find that it just doesn’t fulfil your needs. We’d say,
*Wer bestellt, bezahlt*: even though you cannot use it, you have to pay for
it.

(As opposed to, say, ordering some off-the-shelf part in the internet and
after physically receiving it, finding it doesn’t suit your needs: that one
you’d return for refund [except for delivery costs]).

---

Sayings like *He who pays the piper calls the tune* do not apply in 
the situation I’m after.  In particular, if person B comes along when the towing
service is there and shows that they own the car, the towing service will
**not** tow the car even if person A turns around and pays cash on the barrel. With proof in hand that it’s really B’s car not A’s, the towing company will no longer do A’s bidding regarding the towing of a car that’s not A’s. (The towing company **would** still charge A for having had to
show up unnecessarily, though.)

Comment: As a Brit, I'd say we don't really have much use for such an expression, since we don't really have the kind of "sidewalk cafe culture" associated with mainland Europe (where paying comes long after ordering). In most other contexts, ordering and paying are done at the same time, so this "Who pays?" issue doesn't arise much anyway. What we *do* have is things like *He who pays the piper calls the tune*. And a US favourite of mine *It's your dime* (both meaning that the person who pays gets to choose exactly what he wants, even if that's not what others might choose).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I added some context to clarify. I know the "piper" idiom (in German: wes' Brot ich eß', des' Lied ich sing - I'll sing the tune of him whose bread I eat), but that is for quite different situations. (And in fact, even if the idiom arose from our cafe/restaurant culture, it is rarely if ever used in such context).

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, I don't know of a pithy expression for this, especially after the fact of ordering.  A waiter would ask a plain question like "who had the X?" but there's not really any banter among the customers.  We do have plenty of expressions for paying for *other people's* orders.  "Put it on my tab", "I'll cover this", "I've got this", "It's on me", etc.

Comment: I've certainly seen variations of ***You break it, you buy it*** in downmarket tourist souvenir shops (accidental breakages caused by customer browsing must be paid for).

Comment: *Who orders, pays*! Does it have a connotation that one has to bear the liability of one's action?

Comment: @mahmudkoya: yes it does have that connotation. I did google "who orders, pays" but found only texts by obviously German authors - which made me somewhat wary whether this very literal translation does in fact exist in English. If you know that for sure, please make it an answer.

Comment: @cbeleites I’ve copyedited your interesting question, mostly for formatting and such, but I’ve also added a bit of wording here or there for clarification in ways that I hope will help people from English-speaking countries better understand the situation you’re describing. So if I’ve accidentally added words that don’t fit your scenario, do please feel perfectly free to edit out any unintentional mistakes I’ve made.

Comment: @tchrist: thank you very much for the extensive editing. It does read much nicer and it perfectly covers what I'm after.

Comment: Your two situations are handled differently. Several people eating at separate tables in a restaurant a restaurant might have separate checks ("[dutch treat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_Dutch)")  or one person might pay the whole check, and maybe (depending on the level of _Gemütlichkeit_) try to get money back from his or her dining companions. For the expensive, bespoke items, the establishment will probably make it clear (or expect it to be understood) that payment is ***non-refundable***.

Comment: @Spencer: FumbleFinger brought up the (possible) connection to Central European cafe culture. At least for Germany, cafe or restaurant bills do **not** come to my mind when thinking about "Wer bestellt, bezahlt". They are handled via the waiter's question "separate or together?" and if any other saying applies, it is "den Letzten beißen die Hunde" (the last one gets bitten by the dogs): if some items have not been payed (separate bills, everyone saying what they had), the last one to pay will have to pay for the remainder, including everything others forgot to have put on their bill...

Comment: @cbeleites I referred to a certain German word in my comment as a hint that perhaps some concepts are not fully translatable, especially specific cultural practices.

Comment: @Spencer: that's fine, and "there is no such saying/idiom/concept" *is* an answer to my question. If you think so, please add an answer.

Comment: The flipped form of the "piper" expression may come close: "[Time to/Have to] **pay the piper.**" I assume it's short for "You've called the tune, and now it's time to/you have to pay the piper" but I've only ever heard it in the short-form. It's used similarly to "you've made your bed, now you have to lie in it" or "you've buttered your bread, now you have to eat it", but I don't know that any of those would commonly be used in the situations you've described for literally paying money.

Comment: After racking my brains for idioms about _paying_ and _ordering_ (and getting nowhere), I came up with:  "There's no such thing as a free lunch." It doesn't cover all your bases but gets you there some of the time. "Ain't shit for free" might do a more general job, though at the cost of profanity... if that bothers you.

Comment: @1006a: somehow I think your "reversed piper" may be closest to what I'm looking for. Could you make it an answer so I can accept it, please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following idiom is fit into one of the situations you mentioned.

> **[you pays your money, and you takes your chance(s)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+pays+your+money+and+you+takes+your+chance)**:
>
> - ***When you buy something, you must accept the risk that it will not be what you wanted.***
>
>   *I'm sorry to hear that the laptop you bought on that shady site    doesn't work, but **you pays your money, and you takes your chances**.*
> - **Prov. You must resign yourself to taking risks.; Everything costs    something, but paying for something does not guarantee that you will
>
>     get it. (The grammatical errors are intentional.)**
>
> *Customer: Can you guarantee that this washing machine won't break?*
>
> *Salesman: No   guarantees. **You pays your money and you takes your
>   chances**.*

[(The Free Dictionary by Farlex, Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+pays+your+money%2C+and+you+takes+your+chance(s))

Answer (score 1):

[AmE.com](https://englishlessons.site/2014/11/03/idiom-of-the-week-on-ones-dime/) Idiom  – **On one’s dime**

> at one’s expense

As in the person ordering something is the one who has to pay for it:

person = X

> "The cost of today's lunch is on X's dime!